# Sessions when called by flash

Tags: php, session, cookies, swfupload

Whats the best way to get around PHP's user agent matching for sessions without actually changing the global security setting? I can easily pass the session id from the page containing the swf into the swf.

Note: This is for swfupload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just sending the SID in GET and checking that the user-agent is a flash one.